# Codeigniter: form_open redirects to blank page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been following this tutorial on simple login using CodeIgniter

http://www.iluv2code.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html.

Whenever I click the login button, I get redirected to a blank page instead of getting to the "verifylogin" controller. I tried to change form_open('verifylogin') to form action="verifylogin" just to make sure it reaches the verifylogin. It reaches verifylogin but can't seem to be doing the correct functionalities. Why is that so? Why am i redirected to a blank page when the form is submitted?
Thank you!

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
}

function index() {

  $this->load->helper(array('form'));
  $this->load->view('login_view');
}

}

?>
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</h1>
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
    }

    function index() {

    //This method will have the credentials validation
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

      //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page

      $this->load->view('login_view');

    } else {

      //Go to private area
       redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }

    }

    function check_database($password) {

        //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database

        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        //query the database
        $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

        if($result) {

            $sess_array = array();

            foreach($result as $row) {

                $sess_array = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'username' => $row->username
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);

            }

            return TRUE;

        } else {

            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid       username or password');
            return false;

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. I think you have some error.

Comment: sorry, where will i add it?

Comment: What version of codeigniter you using could be different to what tutorial is because codeigniter 3 lots of changes.

Comment: And also you need to load the secutity helper for using xss_clean in form http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/security_helper.html

Comment: On your action on view make sure matches controller name `form_open(verifylogin')` and  `class Verifylogin extends CI_Controller {}` file name `Verifylogin.php`

Comment: Have you tried to use "form_open(base_url('verifylogin'))". Have you checked It?

Comment: i think you need to load url helper

Answer (score 2):

sometimes index.php prefix before the your page to avoid this use base_url() function before calling the page in form_open();
like :
`echo form_open(base_url()."contact-us");`

but before using base_url() make sure that you have called $this->load->helper('url'); in your associate controller.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');
```

to:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');
```

The `xss_clean` is probably causing the issue, hope it helps. Also make sure if you have not configured your `.htaccess` file to remove `index.php` from the url you need to use `form_open('index.php/verify_login')`

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the url helper??

```
$this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
```

check  it and let me know please